# How do I update lookup tables using data from higher environments

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

At my company, they have the server environments DEV, QA, STAGE, and PROD. Users can update the lookup tables in PROD using the UI. The lower level environments only get refreshed every 6 months, so the lookup tables can get very out of date causing foreign key failures when moving scripts up from the bottom. What ways are there to automate the process of syncing the lookup tables. The servers are not linked.

Comment: How about automated full restores of your DEV database to STAGE etc? 
E.g. when development is complete and tested, the entire database is restored onto STAGE, so you don't have to worry about sync problems.

Comment: The db in question is too large to do a full restore. It won't let me upvote answers, but I think the ssis solution below would do exactly what we need with very little overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick'n'nasty SSIS package that TRUNCATEs the lookup tables on the target server (configurable), then repopulates them from a "higher-status/more current" server (configurable).

(Remember to set IDENTITY INSERT ON, if there are any IDENTITY columns).

Takes minutes to set up.

Comment: I don't have enough rep on here to upvote, but I would upvote this. It was what I had in mind when I put the question on here, but since I have to work with other developers to use SSIS, I was hoping there might be a better way.

Comment: @JonChapman.  Glad it's useful.  You can mark it as answer if you think it's the best solution.  SSIS at this level (clearing tables and copying the data across) is pretty easy to learn, and much clearer and quicker than restoring entire databases.

Answer (score 0):

When you make additions to the Lookup tables as part of a project, script out the INSERTS/UPDATES that were used to change the data in the tables.

Then include those scripts in your releases to other environments.

There are many other ways, but this is how we do it at my current shop, and most of the other shops I've worked in.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage your database with a Visual Studio Database Project, you can use the data and schema comparison tools built into Visual Studio to synchronize the schema and move data from specific tables from one environment to another.  You can also use the SQL Server Import and Export Data tool to move data back and forth between environments.